# How to add data to LiveData

Tags: android, api

In MainActivity I make two calls one by one `getAddress()`, this is code getAddress method:

```
public class RemoteRepository {

    private ApiRequest apiRequest;
    private LiveData<List<AddressResponse>> allAddresses = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public RemoteRepository() {
        apiRequest = RetrofitRequest.getInstance().create(ApiRequest.class);
    }

    public LiveData<List<AddressResponse>> getAddresses() {
        return allAddresses;
    }

    public void getAddress(double query1, double query2) {

        apiRequest.getAddress(query1, query2)
                .enqueue(new Callback<AddressResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AddressResponse> call, Response<AddressResponse> response) {

                        if(response.body() != null) {
                            allAddresses.getValue().add(response.body());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<AddressResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`.

Is there any way to add data from each call to `LiveData<List<AddressResponse>> allAddresses` ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this what you need to change this

```
allAddresses.getValue().add(response.body());
```

to this:

```
allAddresses.postValue(response.body())
```

Answer (score 0):

First it's better to create instance of your **LiveData** in getter method not in top of your class like this:

```
Public LiveData<List<ResponseAddress> getAddress(){
     if(allAddress == Null)
          allAddress = new MutableLiveData ();         
     return allAddress;
 }
```

Then ensure your response body is not null :

```
if(response.body() != null ){
      // Replacement Bellow
  }
```

And in your if statement body just Replace :

```
allAddresses.getValue().add(response.body());
```

With this :

```
allAddresses.setValue(response.body());
```

Answer (score 0):

If want to post or add a task to the main thread of the application whenever there is a change in the value then use:

```
allAddresses.postValue(response.body())
```

While the setValue() method is used to set the changed value i.e. the change value will be dispatched to the active observer of the application:

```
allAddresses.setValue(response.body())
```